# Write a function that accepts a positive integer N and returns N

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

the function should display:  N**!** = XXX - where N is the input number and XXX is the result of calling the function with N.

I'm not sure what this means and when I went to get help they gave me this

```
function factorial(N){
    if (N==0){
        return 1;
    }
    return N = factorial(N - 1); 
}
```

but it's not correct it always outputs one, not the number that's inputted. I'm not sure how to output an exclamation point with the inputted number either.

Comment: do you want to factorial of N?

Comment: `return N * factorial(N-1)`

Comment: Please formulate your question better. State clearly what is your expected output. How is "factorial" related to your question? Who are "they"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's obviously homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is to find-out the factorial of a number this solution would be useful.

The mistake in your code is instead of this line `N =factorial(N - 1)` it should be `N * factorial(N - 1)`

```js
function fact(x) {
   if(x==0) {
      return 1;
   }
   return x * fact(x-1);
}

function run(number) {
    console.log(fact(parseInt(number, 10)));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="val"/>
<input type="button" value="Find factiorial" onclick="run(val.value)">
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to display `N! = XXX`, you need to

1. compute N!
2. build a string N! = XXX
3. display it either in your DOM or via `console.log`

```js
let fac = n => n > 0 ? fac(n - 1) * n : 1;

let n = 3;

let output = `${n}! = ${fac(n)}`;

console.log(output); // 3! = 6
```